# Bringing life savings from KSA to Germany

Tags: taxes, income-tax, international-transfer, germany, saudi-arabia

I recently moved to Germany and my partner is planning to join me in a couple of months.

We used to work in KSA and have a sum of money greater than 10 000 euros saved up from our work back in KSA.

I was wondering what is the process to get the money into Germany and if that money is taxable?